# Using CDN in ASP.NET MVC bundles

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I read the article about [bundling and monification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification), specially about using CDN, but there are some things unclear to me.

Having the example :

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    //            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.UseCdn = true;   //enable CDN support

    //add link to jquery on the CDN
    var jqueryCdnPath = 
        "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js";

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery",
                jqueryCdnPath).Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    // Code removed for clarity.
}
```

1. Is there a possibility to use the `{version}` format of CDN references, like for the "local" ones?
2. What is the point of including in the bundles the already minified version of the script, like *jquery-1.7.1.min.js*? What if it does not exist? Should it not search if the `.min` file exist and/or generate it respectively?

Answer (score 7):

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace MvcApp
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap","https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js").Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css", "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css").Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css"));

            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
            bundles.UseCdn = true;
        }
    }
}
```

What a lot of developers don't realized is that there is an overload for class constructor of ScriptBundle and StyleBundle, which takes two string parameters, for example for the ScriptBundle it would be ScriptBundle(string, string) and for the StyleBundle it would be StyleBundle(string, string).  The first parameter is the virtual path and the second parameter is the cdnPath.

We might be asking yourself, if it takes two parameters, how does MVC know which one to use?  Well, the cdn location is used only when the BundleTable.EnableOptimizations property is set to true.

Setting the EnableOptimization property to true tells MVC to use the use the minified version of the file instead of the regular version.

When this property is set to true, and the cdn path is present MVC will use the cdn path instead of the local virtual path.
There is one more property you have to set to true and that is the bundles.UseCdn.
This tells MVC to use the cdn location instead of the local version.  If the BundleTable.EnableOptimization is set to false, then **the local version is used automatically as a fall back because the cdn version is the minified version**.

Read this blog its clear about your think:

http://www.techjunkieblog.com/2015/06/aspnet-mvc-5-configure-bundleconfig.html

Comment: But if you have many files on the CDN, doesn't this force you to create a bundle for each (because you can't specify the CDN in .include), thereby eliminating the whole point of bundles?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't to my knowledge. But you can keep a table of cdns and populate when the bundles are loaded. When a new version comes out you wish to use, add/replace entry in the db.

   ```
       //get from db
       List<string> cdns = new List<string>();
       foreach (string cdn in cdns)
       {
           bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery",cdn).Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
       }
   ```
2. I agree on the min part. For the doesn't exist part of the question, scroll down and read about "Using a CDN". There's an example to show how to check. You essentially need to have a local copy as backup of you can reference another cdn I suppose.

Comment: Thanks. Mark. but for the first question, I ask concretly for the CDN usage, not the "general" one (local, in occurrence). In the example there is the. I think that for cdn it does ot search the min version, this is why we use it directly in the example.

Comment: My bad, misread it. Can't use versioning since it's a file that resides outside your app. 
An alternative would be to have a table in your db that you can maintain the latest version in a row which in turn dynamically creates your bundle. That way you can change the cdn without having to push your app.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a possibility to use the {version} format of CDN references,
>   like for the "local" ones?

The {version} placeholder is primarily for saving time typing the explicit number so that the build could look for files on local disk. Since the same search could not be done on a remote server, you will need to specify an exact URL explicitly.

> What is the point of including in the bundles the already minified
>   version of the script, like jquery-1.7.1.min.js? What if it does not
>   exist?

The key benefit to go with this bundling syntax is to conditionally switch between different URLs for script and style tags in the final HTML.

When a requested file does not exist, the bundling process will skip it.

> Should it not search if the .min file exist and/or generate it
>   respectively?
>   Yes, it applies minification before bundling as you can see:
>   [image]